# How to Filter Records From Database with multiple Dropdown select in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to filter and fetch data according to drop down selected option .I'm having  total 5 drop downs, any drop downs may be selected or will keep empty.please any one share me how to do  it.

Comment: Please add what you implemented so far.

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: devika and nagessh Please implement the given below  answer.use isset function to check the options are set and append the query.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can append your query based on filter selected. The query will look like

```
$sql = select * from table where 1=1
if(option1){
    $sql .= and column1 = option1 (i:e fname column = fname option)
}
if(option2){
   $sql .= and column2 = option2 (i:e lname column = lname option)
}
```

and so on. In this way your query where clause will get form based on filter selected.